# 14.04 PXE slow boot process (udev/upstart/systemd)

Tags: boot, 14.04, upstart, plymouth, pxe

I've been using a diskless installation of Ubuntu for our department up until Ubuntu 13.04, without any major issues so far.

However, with 14.04, something weird is happening in the boot process (which takes several minutes to complete.)

Looking at the dmesg log, it looks like the problem is related to the initialization of "urandom" and the "nonblocking pool". Any ideas why this would take several minutes when booting on the network (using NFS)?

Extract from dmesg:

```
[   13.013388] pcnet32 0000:00:03.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex
[   13.863447] random: init urandom read with 44 bits of entropy available
[   75.338950] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[  115.543026] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (139) terminated with status 1
[  115.551323] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  155.826797] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (149) terminated with status 1
[  155.827871] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  155.863568] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (152) terminated with status 1
[  155.865184] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  155.884975] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (156) terminated with status 1
[  155.886498] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  158.202482] systemd-udevd[320]: starting version 204
```

It was suggested that `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` were missing and had to be recreated, but this was not the solution.

I would be very grateful for any hint that would point me in a direction to help me solve this issue.

**Update 2014-05-20** -- here is the included bootchart: [image: Bootchart PXE-booted Ubuntu 14.04]

Comment: Could this be related to the "pollinate" feature in 14.04 that is supposed to fetch seed values with random entropy from multiple HTTPS servers during startup? This sounds like a really bad idea to me -- I can't really believe that anyone would implement something like that.

Comment: It certainly could be due to the `pollinate` client. Is the host a VM? Are you booting the 14.04 cloud image? Do you have the `pollinate` package installed (`dpkg -l pollinate`)? And if so, have you edited `/etc/default/pollinate`?

Comment: It's 14.04 desktop and I've tested booting it both in a VM and on a physical computer, with the same results. The package `pollinate` is not installed, so maybe that is not the problem after all.

Comment: You tagged with `systemd`, but are you actually booting with systemd as init or is it a standard Ubuntu install booting with upstart as the init daemon?

Comment: I thought systemd was used by default in 14.04? The systemd packages are installed and as you can see above, there is also a line with systemd-udevd in dmesg.

Comment: No, 14.04 uses upstart. You should have some systemd packages installed but not `systemd` itself. The delay you are seeing might not be due to the `urandom` messages. When I boot a (non-PXE) VM with stock 14.04, I see `init urandom read` at 2.436850 seconds and `nonblocking pool is initialized` at 32.393119 seconds. But other things are able to start in the meantime. And `systemd-udev` starts at 0.696327 seconds. So I think the more important question for your problem is why it takes 150 seconds for `udev` to start. Is it PXE or is it particular to your system?

Comment: You might want to look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting to see if that helps explain your boot times. You might also want to file a bug if no one has any other suggestions to help resolve this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the bootchart package as reported here (division by zero in one of the drawing routines): https://code.google.com/p/pybootchartgui/issues/detail?id=13

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix the bootchart issue by downloading a modified version of pybootchartgui. Bootchart.png is now attached.

Comment: I still don't have an answer, but the bootchart is a good start. This shows that the first 150 seconds of your boot are taken up by some of the early processes run by upstart, including setting your hostname, starting plymouth, reading the hardware clock, starting the ureadahead daemon. So it doesn't seem to be one thing but rather everything running slowly. Even after the 155 second mark, it takes about another 20 seconds to finish fully booting. With this kind of global slowdown, I would look at NFS or network in general. Have the NFS mount options changed? Differences on the NFS server?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Bootchart showed hostname, plymouth and such taking a very long time to start.

Going with intuition thinking they (mostly 'hostname') might want to do something networky when a network connection is available, I made sure there was a working resolv.conf available on the root volume. This solved my problem.